# Catalan Numbers and Geometric Series Combo

Tags: combinatorics, summation, catalan-numbers

Is there a nice (non-summation) representation of the following sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}C_{n}b^n$$ where $b <1$ and $C_{n}$ are the Catalan numbers. Obviously, this can be written as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}C_{n}b^n = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\binom{2n}{n}b^n -\sum_{n=1}^{N}\binom{2n}{n+1}b^n$$

Comment: With $N$ replaced by $\infty$, this would say $C=B-bBC^2$, where $C=C(b)$ and $B=B(b)$ are the ordinary generating functions of Catalan numbers and central binomial coefficients, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a closed-form expression.  We know that $$
\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4b}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{C_nb^n}
$$ is the generating function of the Catalan numbers, and you can try to bound the error with Taylor's formula.

Here the Catalan numbers are indexed starting at $1$, rather than at $0$ as is more common.  I copied this formula from a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/277c/2391b72a284e91bf074f578a59a79eb96aad.pdf) that uses the unusual convention that $C_0=0, C_1=1, C_2=1, C_3=2, ...,$ so the lower index of summation might as well be $1$ as $0$.

Fortuitously, this formula would be easier to use in bounding the error with Taylor's formula than the more common generating function (with a $b$) in the denominator, because it would be easier to calculate the $n$th derivative.

Comment: I think the denominator is $2b$.

Comment: That just depends on whether you start indexing them at $0$ or at $1.$  I copied the formula from a [source](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/277c/2391b72a284e91bf074f578a59a79eb96aad.pdf) that starts at $1$.  The $1$-based form will be more convenient form to use if you try to bound the error using Taylor's formula, because the $n$th derivative will be easier to calculate.  You can adjust to the more common $0$-based system afterwards.

Comment: Well, your right-hand side has $n$ starting at $0$, that’s why I thought it needed this minor correction.

Comment: You are right.  There's a typo on the right.  I will correct the answer.  Thanks for pointing this out.